# XAMPP Control Panel -Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am unable to run MYSQL server in XAMPP control panel, when I click on start button then following error occurs given below:

```
4:48:58 PM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
4:48:58 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
4:49:00 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
4:49:00 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
4:49:00 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
4:49:00 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
4:49:00 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
4:49:00 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
4:49:00 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
4:49:00 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
4:49:25 PM  [main]  Executing "c:\xampp\mysql\data"
```

here is the mysql error log:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.14 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 171
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-22 16:47:41 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-09-22 16:47:42 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-09-22 16:47:42 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2020-09-22 16:47:42 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2020-09-22 16:47:42 0 [ERROR] Aborting
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.14 started; log sequence number 300306; transaction id 171
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Please help me solve this error as soon as possible as I want to use phpmyadmin in XAMPP to get started with my project,
Thank you.

Comment: It seems 3306 PORT is already in use. Please check what's running on the port 3306.

Comment: @SaachiTech yes there is already mysql database installed on my system. I want to use phpmyadmin in XAMPP how to proceed further

Comment: You probably alreay have MySQL running. Please use ```netstat -an``` to check 3306 port used by which service.

Comment: try ```netstat -a -n -o | find "3306"```

Comment: yes @SaachiTech i ran the command netstat -an the port 3306 is in listening status.

Comment: That means MySQL is already running so you don’t need to start it from Xampp.

Comment: What to do next to solve this error can mysql service of xampp be given another port?

Answer (score 0):

> 2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
> 2020-09-22 16:48:58 0 [ERROR] Aborting

It seems that port 3306 (default) is already in use. You could work around issue by changing to another port.

You open `my.ini`

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password = your_password 
port = 3306
socket = "xampp / mysql / mysql.sock"
```

change `3306` --> `another port`

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "xampp / mysql / mysql.sock"
```

change `3306` --> `another port`

Then, you restart mysql service.

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem solved the error was port 3360 is not available as mysql server installed on my system was using the same port,so i went to services in search bar and then once opened went to mysql clicked on it then clicked on stop service. Then restart xampp and start mysql then it is running well in windows 10 you need to check with other OS.

Answer (score 0):

I admit @soumya Pillai answer!

I've stopped MySQL service first.

[image: Windows Services]

Then started MySQL in XAMPP. Now it's started to running!.

I'm using XAMPP V3.3.0 in windows 10 machine!